# Ajax / Jquery Autocomplete with JSON data does not show background style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, ajax

I want to render Ajax / Jquery Autocomplete in my Spring App but unable to show background style I get result as shown

[image: Some results]

my Autocomplete code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
    //attach autocomplete
    $("#tagQuery").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 500,
        //define callback to format results
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("/getTags", request, function(result) {
                response($.map(result, function(item) {
                    return {
                        // following property gets displayed in drop down
                        label: item.tagTitle,
                        // following property gets entered in the textbox
                        value: item.tagTitle,
                        // following property is added for our own use
                        tag_url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/" + item.tagId + "/" + item.tagTitle
                    }
                }));
            });
        },

        //define select handler
        select : function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#selected_tags span").append('<a href=" + ui.item.tag_url + " target="_blank">'+ ui.item.label +'</a>');
                //$("#tagQuery").value = $("#tagQuery").defaultValue
                var defValue = $("#tagQuery").prop('defaultValue');
                $("#tagQuery").val(defValue);
                $("#tagQuery").blur();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

#### UPDATE

Adding line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

solved issue of ui it now looks good

[image: Updated result image]

> but when I select any value it is not placed in input text and how can I add comma separated multiple results in input box.

please any help is a day saving...